# get JAVA_OPTS at runtime

Tags: java, tomcat

My app is deployed on Tomcat and I've configured the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable in `/etc/default/tomcat7`.

There seem to be a million different places where these variables can be provided to Tomcat, so I want to check that the values I'm providing are what's actually being used. Is there something I can inspect at runtime to determine the value of this variable. I checked `System.getProperties()`, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for *just* the property overrides and JVM arguments, you can use [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html):

```
RuntimeMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
System.out.println(mxBean.getInputArguments());
```

For example, running with the following command-line:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Dtest.prop=foo com.example.sandbox.RuntimeMXBeanExample
```

I get the following output:

```
[-Xms512m, -Xmx1024m, -Dtest.prop=foo]
```

Note that this does *not* include arguments passed to the `main()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.getenv("JAVA_OPTS")` as suggested.

If you don't want to modify code than you can use some of those methods

Java Tools

1. `jps -v` displays Java processes with arguments
2. `jvisualvm` connects to Java process and let's you inspect number of properties including MXBeans

GNU/Linux tools

1. `ps e` displays environment variables passed to processes

Answer (score 1):

One important thing, although post is old.  Whatever variable you are passing it should be before the class name you are executing else it will be ignored.

**Below will work:**

Example: java -classpath . -Dformat=xls -DTabname=\"Base data new\" com.cg.bench.GenerateReport

**Below will NOT work:**

WRONG Example: java -classpath . com.cg.bench.GenerateReport -Dformat=xls -DTabname=\"Base data new\"