# Enable JMX with spring boot repackage

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

I'm want to enable JMX for my spring boot application and tried everything but without success. I think, the problem is, that I'm using the `repackage` option of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

At the moment I did the following:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1617 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
java -jar target/myapp-1.0.0.jar
```

But when I start the application, it does not listen on port 1617. I cannot connect from a JMX client and `ss -tulpen` also does not list the port.

I also tried it by passing the `-D...` parameters directly. I also tried it with `--com.sun...` and thought Spring boot could handle them this way. I also tried many other things on multiple machines, without success.

Some further information:

- My application does *not* use any `spring-boot` parent.
- I'm trying this on an ArchLinux system.
- I don't have any special iptables configuration, all ports should be available on the configured ip.
- Spring boot version: 1.4.1.RELEASE
- Java version: `openjdk version "1.8.0_112"`

What am I doing wrong and where can I find a documentation with help on that?

**UPDATE:** I added some lines for reading and printing the passed `JAVA_OPTS` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193128/get-java-opts-at-runtime)). When I start the application through IntelliJ and setting the VM options to the `JAVA_OPTS` value from above, it works. The passed options are printed and the VM is listening on port 1617. When I start the application using `java -jar my.jar -Dcom.sun....` the parameters are not printed and the VM is still not listening on port 1617.

Comment: I think you are using [wrong way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011311/running-java-with-java-opts-env-variable) to pass JMX parameters. Try to pass them directly after `java` command.

Comment: By "it does not listen on port 1617", do you mean that you can't connect or that you've looked it up in netstat?

Comment: @MaximDobryakov As said. I already did that. I ran the java command also with `java -Dcom.sun.... -jar ...`.

Comment: @chrylis `ss` is the new `netstat`. So I can't connect and `netstat`/`ss` does not list it

Comment: I'll switch to `ss` when kernel 13.0 removes the proc entries. Off my lawn!

Comment: Using IntelliJ it works but when running the jar file it still does not work. See my update above for details.

Comment: Even if I pass `-Xmx512m` it does not work for the jar file but it works in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved! I still don't know why it does not work with `JAVA_OPTS` but I know what I did wrong when passing the options directly: It seems that I always passed the `-jar ...` option *before* the `-Dcom.sun...` options. But what I found out now:

> **The order of these options is essential!**
>
> What? Really?
>
> Yes!

So, the way that works for me now:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1617 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -jar my.jar
```

and this one does **not** work:

```
java -jar my.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1617 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for this whole day!

Comment: This is because you are running a jar: everything after `-jar my.jar` is passed as arguments to your main method (`String[] args`), not as JVM options.